# Dealing with date using reactivemongo and a json api

Tags: json, scala, date, playframework, reactivemongo

I am currently using a object containing a BSONDateTime :

```
case class Datez(date: BSONDateTime)
```

When this a list of Datez object is transformed to json the following string is generated :

```
[{"date":{"$date":1408053600000}}, {"date":{"$date":1321052400000}}]
```

But what I am expecting client side is the following :

```
[{"date":1408053600000}, {"date":1321052400000}]
```

To do so I a using play.api.libs.json.Json :

```
implicit val datezFormat = Json.format[Datez]
Json.arr(List(Datez...))
```

How can I get rid of the "$date" part with the smallest impact to the server side code ?

PS : I am doing this to ease angular compatibility but their is maybe another way.

Comment: What json library do you use? Solution: Write your own Json codec for Datez.

Comment: I am using play framework  play.api.libs.json.Json formatters. My goal is actually to avoid any specific code for this task.